# Will Windows reinstall wipe hard disk and reinstall drivers?

Tags: windows-10, reset

I have an ASUS ZenBook UX306U that I have completely messed up. I have about three operating systems installed, and lots of corrupted apps and files. I want to reset my computer with a clean installation of Windows, so I made a backup of the few files I want to keep. Then I went to Settings to where it says this:

[image: Reset this PC Image].

I clicked on the button and got this:

[image: Choose an option Image].

I think the option for me is `Remove everything`, but here is my real question:

1. Will clicking that button erase the entire hard drive? (I want it to)
2. When it reinstalls Windows, will it come installed with all the apps and drivers that came with my computer (i.e. AudioWizard)? (I want that, too)

Comment: 1: If not you can manually delete their partitions and extend your main one back. 2: As long as Asus setup their recovery partition like everyone else yes it would reinstall their software.

Comment: If you want to get rid of drivers, use neither Reset option, and use the Refresh option instead

Comment: @Unfundednut can you make this an answer?

Comment: @Ramhound I _don't_ want to get rid of drivers.

Comment: So why are you going to use the Reset feature if thats the case?  It's going to keep your personal files, in the user's profile directory, I don't believe that includes device drivers.

Comment: I will say it in another way.  Reset will not touch your partitions.  It is going to install along side of your current installation, then transfer your user(s) data to the new installation, and place the old installation in `Windows.old`  It is trivial to get AudioWizard from ASUS, there a reason, you want to keep these third-party programs installed which go counter to you wanting to "reinstall" Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound how can I comepletely wipe my hard disk and comepletely reinstall Windows fresh? Also I already have Windows.old for some reason. Will unfundednut's answer work?

Comment: His answer certainly will work, but it won't solve, corrupted applications and files.  You have Windows.old either becaus you installed Windows on a partition that had Windows, upgraded Windows to a newer version, or installed a Windows 10 feature update.  You reinstall Windows, by getting rid of your partitions, then installing Windows 10 or like I did use the Refresh feature.

Comment: @Ramhound Let's [do this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56332/discussion-between-cello-guy-and-ramhound).

Comment: @CelloGuy [How to use 'Refresh Windows' to do a clean install of Windows 10 Anniversary Update](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-refresh-tool-do-clean-install-windows-10)

Comment: The drivers are stored in this folder C:\windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository    back it up.  Then you can go into the device manager on your fresh install, and update the drivers from the back up copy.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not clean up the partitions you can use disk manager or diskpart to clear the other partitions out and extend them.

1. Click start and type in `diskmgmt.msc` right click on the result and choose Run As Administrator.
2. Next delete the partitions that belong to Linux. These are generally blank for Volume and File system.
3. Next right click on your C: volume and you can extend it.

As long as Asus setup their recovery partition like everyone else yes it would reinstall their software and drivers.